# Does PHP eval() work similarly to including? (load page with code in DB)

Tags: php, frameworks, include, eval

If someone uses eval() in PHP, does this method behave exactly like including the code which is in the string, except the error raised when there is a parse error?
I am aware of security issues, this is just for a temporary, but necessary solution.
Thank you.
**Edit:** How would you make a Joomla like small framework, where there are modules on pages, but with code loaded from database? This option is much more flexible, than making modules and components for every tiny problem and feature, pages are generated with 1 PHP file, from database, content based on page number.

Comment: There are some differences mentioned in the comments in the documentation https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: You can do it for very specific code blocks, but it will be hell of slower if you use it for everything, specially if you load all the code from the DB. Most changes are related to include paths.

Answer (score 0):

It provides the same result, it does not necessarily behave the same. The most notable differences are that `eval` is significantly slower since it has to execute the parse step (circumventing any opcache) with every iteration and it has to be bootstrapped ontop of the running VM. Another difference is that include allows for return values since it behaves more like an expression than a function/construct.